# how to create triangle chart (Funnel Chart/Pyramid Chart) in php?

Tags: php, html, graph, charts, report

I have a requirement to create a triangle chart(Funnel Chart/Pyramid Chart) in php like below;

[image: triangle chart]
<sub>(source: [tabbforum.com](http://assets.tabbforum.com/charts/sales/chart.gif))</sub>

is there any api? library, script etc.

Please help..

Comment: Normally called a Funnel Chart

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker , any php, html, html5 example for Funnel Chart.

Comment: If you google "Funnel Chart", you're likely to find a whole host of libraries - most of those I know are front-end js or flash; but I'm sure some of the php chart libraries like jpgraph or graphpite support them as well

Comment: I used; http://www.jchartfx.com/jChartFXGallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe sth like this! it needs some calculations!

```
#trapezoid {
    border-top: 50px solid red;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}#trapezoid2 {
    border-top: 50px solid green;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
#trapezoid3 {
    border-top: 50px solid blue;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}


html: 
<div id="trapezoid"></div><div id="trapezoid2"></div><div id="trapezoid3"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, its working but how will i automate it, you have 3 trapezoid's. i dont know how much each report will have.. it will be calculated on runtime..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [extJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/)? It supports HTML5 standards, you could create from simple pie charts to much more complex GUI's. [Here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/charts/pie/) are some samples

You could use extJS for free as long as it is non-commercial and profitable.

Adding onto that there are many CDN that are already caching extJS Core. One example is the [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#ext-core).

There are additional libraries that could probably solved your problem [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/learn/docs.php), and [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/). The following js scripts have or do support *Vertical Funnel Chart*.

Comment: extJS not having Funnel Chart..

Comment: I Used; http://www.jchartfx.com/jChartFXGallery/